# How to change my css to achieve the desired layout ？

Tags: html, css, dom

Hi I am designing a blog site using pure html and css and I have some design in mind. Currently it looks like before graph and I would like to achieve after graph. Right now all these classes are in inline-block and I do not want to change the dom structure. Please refer to this code snippet for implementation:

https://jsfiddle.net/yueeee/vb1we2tk/4/

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.meta {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  max-width: 200px; /*in large resolution dont always want width to be 12%*/
  margin-right: 40px;
  /* background-color: transparent; */
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align:top; /*always align to the top of container*/
}

.content {
  width: 30%;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  vertical-align:top; /*always align  to the top of container*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="time">
        <p>2020/12/09<br>22:18:35</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tag">
        <p>tag1</p>
        <p>tag2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content post">
      <div class="text">
        <h2> title </h2>
        <p>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
          </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The difficulty I met is how do I set metadata's height equals to content. I checked solution on setting container as table and metadata/ content as table-cell. However, it would cause some other styling issue so I still want to keep everything as inline-block. The other way I am thinking is to set the height of metadata equal to container. It failed because container does not height attribute. I tried something like setting height = 100% cause I do not want a stable height but also did not work.

Need your advice.

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

Comment: Look into flexbox for `.container`

Comment: The best source for practice the flex property on this website (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Use flex in design and enjoy your life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best choice in these cases is to use the flex property. I added some Properties to both the .container and .meta selectors and deleted some, act like code to get the desired result.

```css
    .container {
      display: flex;
      padding: 10px 40px;
      padding-left: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

.meta {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 10%;
    margin-right: 40px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

    .content {
      width: 30%;
      display:inline-block;
      padding: 20px 30px;
      background-color: white;
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="meta">
          <div class="time">
            <p>2020/12/09<br>22:18:35</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tag">
            <p>tag1</p>
            <p>tag2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content post">
          <div class="text">
            <h2> title </h2>
            <p>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
              </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```